# Accessing global variable in view using context processor in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-context

Assuming I have a context processor:

```
def title(request):
   return {'titles': 'mytitle'}
```

I can access this variable in template as `{{ titles }}`.

But how can I do so in a view?

```
def myview(request):
    print request.titles
```

doesn't seem to work - `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'titles'`

---

Or maybe there is a better approach (than context processors) to have global variables accessible in both views and templates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context processors aren't in any way global variables. They are simply functions that are run when a RequestContext is initiated, which add items to that context. So they're only available wherever you have a RequestContext, ie in a template.

Your examples don't really give a good idea of what variables you're looking to access. If it's just some constants you want to use everywhere, a good way is to define them somewhere central, say in settings.py, and import that module wherever you need it - plus use a context processor to add them to the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Defining constans in that way and using context processor to add them to the context is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Add your context processor method path (folder.context_processor.application_context) to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

in my case application_context is the method which i defined inside file context_processor.py
and method "application_context"  returns {'titles': 'mytitle'}

if you want to use "title" as global variable in views use it in this way

```
global_var = RequestContext(request).get("app_config")
titles = global_var.get("titles")
print titles
```

The only advantage is "Same variable 'titles' will be visible for templates and also in your views"

Comment: What is `"app_config"` in this example?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the data in your views, it's cleaner to use Middleware in conjunction with a Context Processor:

1. Create a trivial custom middleware to store some data on the request object, say at `request.x` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37074231/317110)). Now you can access this in your views directly.
2. Enable `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to have request.x accessible from your templates.

See my related question: [Django: How to provide context to all views (not templates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073856/django-how-to-provide-context-to-all-views-not-templates)